# Google Cloud Composer and MS SQL using Cloud Proxy

Tags: airflow

I'm building a Cloud SQL (MS SQL Server) to BigQuery integration using Airflow on GCP (Composer). I've setup a cloud SQL Proxy in GKE cluster which is running fine, no errors there:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: cloud-sql-proxy
  name: cloud-sql-proxy
  namespace: cloud-sql-to-bq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: cloud-sql-proxy
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: cloud-sql-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /cloud_sql_proxy
        - -instances=[INSTANCE-NAME]=tcp:0.0.0.0:1433
        image: b.gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: airflow-sqlproxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1433
          protocol: TCP
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: default-pool
      restartPolicy: Always
```

My DAG:

```
dag = DAG('mssql-export-demo', catchup=False, default_args=default_args)
cloud_storage_bucket_name = 'mssql-export-test'


export_customers = MsSqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='export_analysis',
    sql='SELECT * FROM vwAnalysis;',
    bucket=cloud_storage_bucket_name,
    filename='data/customers/export.json',
    schema_filename='schemas/export.json',
    mssql_conn_id='cloud_sql_proxy_conn',
    dag=dag
)
```

I've also created a connection in Airflow to point to **cloud_sql_proxy_conn**.
When I run the DAG I get the following error:

```
[2020-11-28 01:59:20,555] {taskinstance.py:1153} ERROR - Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 636, in pymssql.connec
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1964, in _mssql.connec
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 683, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init_
_mssql.MSSQLDriverException: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason
```

There's no other error message so this makes it quite difficult to debug. Anybody have experience with MS SQL on Cloud SQL and Composer to help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow now provides CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator which means there's no need of setting up a cloud SQL proxy in GKE.